# Programmatically redirecting an ASP.NET web service call to the same service in a different host

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service developed in ASP.NET running in 2 different hosts. Now I need to redirect some of the calls (depending on settings stored in a database for the user) from just one of the hosts to the other host. Only some calls have to be redirected and I can't modify the clients which are calling the web service, so it has to be transparent for them. Any ideas how to proceed?

Edit: it's a SOAP service (asmx). The client's are android and IOS apps developed in Visual Studio.

Comment: One option would be to return a 302 (Redirect) response with the new URL. Clients are supposed to be able to handle redirection requests. BTW what do you mean "web service"?  A SOAP service like WCF or an HTTP API built using MVC or WebAPI? In MVC you could use a simple `return Redirect("http://www.google.com");`

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirements include reading from a DB, and making a choice based on the identity of the user, it seems clear that even in the case of a redirect from service A to service B, service A must necessarily do at least *some* work before redirecting.

Since that is happening anyway, then perhaps the easiest thing to do is to just call Service B directly from service A when necessary; in other words, just make service A a client of service B. Note that this will not actually *redirect* to B, but rather *forward* calls there, which will mean that the response from B will also have to go via A.

---

**PS:** I'm assuming that the services A and B are basically identical, but that they have access to different resources of some kind (e.g. access to different databases perhaps?). You specified explicitly that you needed to redirect from just *one* of the hosts, but if you solve your problem by allowing each instance of the service to be a client of another instance of the same service, and make this configurable, then you could let both of them redirect to each other if necessary. You might not need it right now, but it might be a useful option in the future, and it probably won't cause any extra overhead anyway.

Comment: You are right, English is not my mother language and I wrote 'redirect' when I was really thinking in 'forward'. It is the exact same service installed in 2 different hosts, each one with its own database and resources. This is temporary, we are migrating from host A to host B but are doing it in gradually. For some months we will have most customers in old host A and a few customers in new host B. This service is used by an smartphone app. That app connects to host A, but if the customer is in host B the call must be forwarded to host B transparently.

Comment: The service in host A will be configured to allow forwarding through web.config. We'll of course need to add the forwarding code to each WebMethod. But how can I easily invoke the same WebMethod in a remote host? Take into account that the service defines some types for parameters and returned results.